# mysql query include zero in count with groupby

Tags: mysql

I have looked at the examples but still need direction. My query works but doesn't include the zero counts in the results - not interested about mysqli or pdo, just stuck on a query and need a solid before I pull my hair out. How do I adjust the below so it would include zeros in the count?

```
SELECT users.user_id,
       users.contact_person,
       users.company,
       users.country,
       users.pic_small,
       users.website,
       COUNT(*)
FROM trading
JOIN users ON users.user_id = trading.user_id
WHERE users.trader_or_bond = %s
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY count(trading.user_id) DESC
```

Comment: if the count is zero, then those records don't exist (or are filtered out by the where clause). if they don't exist, how can you expect to return something of them? maybe a `left join` would be more appropriate?

Comment: show us what is the result without GROUP BY AND COUNT(*) ?

Comment: and/or maybe an expected output by some given input example.

Comment: If you're not interesting in mysql_ vs PDO, you could just take the PHP tag out.

Comment: I basically need to return everything from the users table and a count (including zeros) of posts they have made to the trading table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you just want to move the `where` clause to a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.contact_person, u.company, u.country, u.pic_small, u.website,
       SUM(u.trader_or_bond = %s)
FROM trading t JOIN
     users u
     ON u.user_id = t.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY count(t.user_id) DESC;
```

EDIT:

For your revised requirement, use a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.contact_person, u.company, u.country, u.pic_small, u.website,
       SUM(u.trader_or_bond = %s and t.user_id is not null)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     trading t 
     ON u.user_id = t.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY count(t.user_id) DESC;
```

Comment: appreciate the feedback - all the queries returned the same without zeros included so maybe my understanding is incorrect. I want to include everyone from the users table and do a count of relating ids in the trading table - if there aren't any - return 0

Comment: @Jeff . . . If you want all users, why are you filtering on `users.trader_or_bond = %s`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this? add the ifnull part.. there have to be null returned though for this to return zero's you may need to change your join to a LEFT join and add the conditional where to the join

```
SELECT u.user_id,
       u.contact_person,
       u.company,
       u.country,
       u.pic_small,
       u.website,
       IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) as counter
FROM trading t
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id = t.user_id
   AND u.trader_or_bond = %s
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(u.user_id) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Move you where part in on clause and change join to  left join for a null row from `trading` table count evaluates it as 0

```
SELECT 
  users.user_id,
  users.contact_person,
  users.company,
  users.country,
  users.pic_small,
  users.website,
  COUNT(trading.user_id) 
FROM
  trading 
  LEFT JOIN users 
    ON users.user_id = trading.user_id 
AND  users.trader_or_bond = % s 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(trading.user_id) DESC
```